# Check message for presence

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to make a bot check for a message on the server in a certain channel, but I get a

> Promise { pending }

and I don’t know how to work with it

```
let loadmsg = client.channels.cache.get('id_channel').messages.fetch('id_mess')
console.log(loadmsg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
client.channels.cache.get('id_channel').messages.fetch('id_mess').then(loadmsg => {
    console.log(loadmsg)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: (node:7704) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message

Comment: Yes, you should have error handling too... but this means Discord does not recognise the message you sent. So this is a new problem.

Comment: Edited to include the error handling. Note that Someone Special and I have answered your question, though, so you should accept one or the other as the answer, then post a new question if you can't work out why Discord is not accepting your API call.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see a `Promise { pending }` error, it is because you are expecting a [promise response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

You can use promise chaining, or async/await to get the value.

For example

```
const someFunction = async () => {
    const results = await PromiseFunction();
    console.log(results)
}
```

OR

```
const someFunction = () => {
      PromiseFunction().then( data => console.log(data))
}
```

In your case you may use

```
const myFunction = async () => { // <-- add the async keyword
    let loadmsg = await client.channels.cache.get('id_channel').messages.fetch('id_mess')
    console.log('loadmsg', loadmsg)
}
```

Comment: (node:10396) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message